# Connection timeout on Gunicorn server for Django project

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I am new to Django. I have done the polls tutorial and am now going through Lightweight Django by Elman and Lavin. I am currently making a single-file Django app as per Chapter 1 of the book (link [here](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781491945940_sampler.pdf)) - I have gotten to page 7. I installed Gunicorn and ran the command `gunicorn hello --log-file=-`. Everything seems to be running normally:

```
[2015-07-08 18:13:36 +0000] [9419] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-07-08 18:13:36 +0000] [9419] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (9419)
[2015-07-08 18:13:36 +0000] [9419] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-07-08 18:13:36 +0000] [9422] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9422
```

But when I navigate to 104.130.130.222:0000, I get a connection timed out error. My log remains unchanged as well. I have tried accessing the page from a different network to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I know nothing about servers or Gunicorn, and am a Django beginner too, so the problem might be obvious - I haven't found any good help on the internet so far. I am working remotely on a Linux server (Red hat 6.4) from a Mac running 10.9.5)

My code:

```
 1 # Hello!
 2 
 3 import sys
 4 
 5 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 6 from django.http import HttpResponse
 7 from django.conf.urls import url
 8 from django.conf import settings
 9 
10 
11 def index(request):
12     return HttpResponse('Hello World')
13 
14 settings.configure(
15     DEBUG=True,
16     SECRET_KEY='thisisthesecretkey',
17     ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
18     MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(
19         'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
20         'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
21         'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
22     ),
23 )
24 
25 urlpatterns = (
26     url(r'^$', index),
27     )
28 
29 
30 application = get_wsgi_application()
31 
32 if __name__ == "__main__":
33     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
34 
35     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are going to 104.130.130.222. The server is listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000, that is the address you should use.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Oh wow, that was dumb. It's because to get around my work's firewall, when I ran the Django runserver command, I had to host on my own IP and view on a separate network. Forgot that Gunicorn defaults back to 127.0.0.1.  Bound to my IP and port 8000 and it works now.